# Age comparsion for Zebra Riddle

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle, eclipse-clp

I'm trying to solve a logic riddle similar to the Einstein riddle with ECLiPSe Prolog via CLP:

> A band has 6 jazz-musicians, no one is younger than 70 years old. Every artist has written a different song.
>
> The used instruments are: a piano at position 1 (outer left side of the band), a flute at position 2 (on the right side of position 1), the drums at position 3 (on the right side of position 2), a double bass at position 4 (on the right side of position 3), a saxophon at position 5 (on the right side of position 4) and a trumpet at position 6 (outer right side of the band).
>
> The first names of the artists are: Andi, Cornelius, Fritz, Markus, Pete, Walter.
> The last names of the artists are: Bramkamp, Franke, Karolewicz, Lueg, Schlüter, Weidemann.
> The ages of the artists are: 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82.
> The the title of the songs are: Im Bermudadreieck, Jupps-Eck-Blues, Krösken-Tanz, Legende vom Bergmann, Sally's Dog, Wanne-Eickel-Blues.
>
> Clue 1: The man at the piano ist at least two years older than the double bass user.
> Clue 2: One position further to *Lueg's* right is *Walter*. *Walter* is also one position further to the left than *Sally's Dog* composer.
> Clue 3: The man on position 5 is one year younger than *Pete* and one year older than the composer of *Im Bermudadreieck*.
> Clue 4: One position further to the right than the *77 year old* artist is the composer of *Wanne-Eickel-Blues*.
> Clue 5: One position further to right than *Fritz* is *Franke*. *Franke* is at least 3 years older than the composer of *Legende von Bergmann*. This composer is older than *Schlüter*.
> Clue 6: One position further to the right than *Cornelius* is the *80 years old Weidemann*. *Weidemann* is also one position further to the left than *Karolewicz*. None of them is the composer of *Krösken-Tanz*.
> Clue 7: *Schlüter*, composer of *Jupps-Eck-Blues*, is one position further to the right than *Markus*. *Schlüter* is one position further to the left than *Andi*.

I'm totally new to Prolog, thanks to http://www.hakank.org/bprolog/ and http://www.hakank.org/bprolog/a_round_of_golf.pl I was able to get most of the code done. Currently I stuck on *Clue 4*, I don't know how to combine the position (1..6) of the 77 year old artist with with the Age List (76..80:82).

```
go :-
        
    N = 6,
    
    Piano = 1,
    Flute = 2,
    Drums = 3,
    DoubleBass = 4,
    Saxophon = 5,
    Trumpet = 6,
    Instrument = [Piano, Flute, Drums, DoubleBass, Saxophon, Trumpet],
    InstrumentS = ['Piano', 'Flute', 'Drums', 'DoubleBass', 'Saxophon', 'Trumpet'],
    
    FirstName = [Andi, Cornelius, Fritz, Markus, Pete, Walter], 
    FirstNameS = ['Andi', 'Cornelius', 'Fritz', 'Markus', 'Pete', 'Walter'],
    FirstName :: 1..N,
    
    LastName = [Bramkamp, Franke, Karolewicz, Lueg, Schlueter, Weidemann],
    LastNameS = ['Bramkamp', 'Franke', 'Karolewicz', 'Lueg', 'Schlüter', 'Weidemann'],
    LastName :: 1..N,
    
    Song = [Bermudadreieck, Jupps, Kroesken, Legende, Sally, Wanne],
    SongS = ['Im Bermudadreieck', 'Jupps-Eck-Blues', 'Krösken-Tanz', 
    'Legende vom Bergmann', 'Sally`s Dog', 'Wanne-Eickel-Blues'],
    Song :: 1..N,
    
    length(Age ,N),
    Age :: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82],
    Age = [Age_Piano, Age_Flute, Age_Drums, Age_DoubleBass, Age_Saxophon, Age_Trumpet],

    alldifferent(FirstName), 
    alldifferent(LastName),
    alldifferent(Age),
    alldifferent(Song),

    % Clue 1 ---
    % The man at the piano ist at least two years older than the double bass user.
    Age_Piano #>= Age_DoubleBass + 2, 
    
    % Clue 2 ---
    % One position further to Lueg's right is Walter. 
    % Walter is also one position further to the left than Sally's Dog composer.
    Walter #= Lueg + 1, 
    Walter #= Sally - 1, 
    
    % Clue 3 ---
    % The man on position 5 is one year younger than Pete 
    % and one year older than the composer of Im Bermudadreieck.

    element(Pete, Age, Age_Pete),
    element(Bermudadreieck, Age, Age_Bermudadreieck),
    
    Pete #\= 5, 
    Bermudadreieck #\= 5,
    Age_Saxophon #= Age_Pete - 1,
    Age_Saxophon #= Age_Bermudadreieck + 1,
    
    % Clue 4 ---
    % One position further to the right than the 77 year old artist is the composer of Wanne-Eickel-Blues.
    element(Wanne, Age, Age_Wanne),
    
    Age_Wanne #\= 77, 
    
    % Clue 5 ---
    % One position further to right than Fritz is Franke. 
    % Franke is at least 3 years older than the composer of Legende von Bergmann. 
    % This composer is older than Schlüter.
    
    element(Franke, Age, Age_Franke),
    element(Legende, Age, Age_Legende),
    element(Schlueter, Age, Age_Schlueter),
    
    Franke #= Fritz + 1,
    Franke #\= Legende,
    Franke #\= Schlueter,
    Age_Franke #>= Age_Legende + 3,
    Age_Legende #> Age_Schlueter,
    
    % Clue 6 ---
    % One position further to the right than Cornelius is the 80 years old Weidemann. 
    % Weidemann is also one position further to the left than Karolewicz. 
    % None of them is the composer of Krösken-Tanz.
    
    element(Weidemann, Age, Age_Weidemann),
    
    Age_Weidemann #= 80,
    Weidemann #= Cornelius + 1,
    Weidemann #= Karolewicz - 1,
    Weidemann #\= Kroesken,
    Cornelius #\= Kroesken,
    Karolewicz #\= Kroesken,
    
    % Clue 7 ---
    % Schlüter, composer of Jupps-Eck-Blues, is one position further to the right than Markus. 
    % Schlüter is one position further to the left than Andi.
    Schlueter #= Jupps,
    Schlueter #= Markus + 1,
    Schlueter #= Andi - 1,

    term_variables([FirstName, LastName, Age, Song], Vars),

    labeling(Vars).
```

Answer (score 2):

Implemented working solution and nice presentation of results, thanks to http://www.hakank.org/eclipse/. The trick was to create another list `AgePos` with all ages and the given the position range `[1..N]`.

```
[...]
AgePos = [AP76, AP77, AP78, AP79, AP80, AP82],
AgePos :: 1..N,
[...]
```

Then I linked this list with `Age`.

```
[...]
nth1(AP76, Age, Age_AP76),
Age_AP76 #= 76,
[...]
```

The full code, with some adjustments

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(listut).

go :-
    
N = 6,
Range = 1..N,

Piano = 1,
Flute = 2,
Drums = 3,
DoubleBass = 4,
Saxophon = 5,
Trumpet = 6,
Instrument = [Piano, Flute, Drums, DoubleBass, Saxophon, Trumpet],
InstrumentS = ['piano', 'flute', 'drums', 'double bass', 'saxophon', 'trumpet'],

FirstName = [Andi, Cornelius, Fritz, Markus, Pete, Walter], 
FirstNameS = ['Andi', 'Cornelius', 'Fritz', 'Markus', 'Pete', 'Walter'],
FirstName :: Range,

LastName = [Bramkamp, Franke, Karolewicz, Lueg, Schlueter, Weidemann],
LastNameS = ['Bramkamp', 'Franke', 'Karolewicz', 'Lueg', 'Schlüter', 'Weidemann'],
LastName :: Range,

Song = [Bermudadreieck, Jupps, Kroesken, Legende, Sally, Wanne],
SongS = ['Im Bermudadreieck', 'Jupps-Eck-Blues', 'Krösken-Tanz', 
'Legende vom Bergmann', 'Sally`s Dog', 'Wanne-Eickel-Blues'],
Song :: Range,

AgePos = [AP76, AP77, AP78, AP79, AP80, AP82],
AgePos :: Range,

dim(Age, [N]),
Age :: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82],
collection_to_list(Age, AgeList),

alldifferent(FirstName), 
alldifferent(LastName),
alldifferent(Age),
alldifferent(AgePos),
alldifferent(Song),

% Age Setting

nth1(AP76, AgeList, Age_AP76),
nth1(AP77, AgeList, Age_AP77),
nth1(AP78, AgeList, Age_AP78),
nth1(AP79, AgeList, Age_AP79),
nth1(AP80, AgeList, Age_AP80),
nth1(AP82, AgeList, Age_AP82),

Age_AP76 #= 76,
Age_AP77 #= 77,
Age_AP78 #= 78,
Age_AP79 #= 79,
Age_AP80 #= 80,
Age_AP82 #= 82,

% Clue 1 ---
% The man at the piano ist at least two years older than the double bass user.

nth1(Piano, AgeList, Age_Piano),
nth1(DoubleBass, AgeList, Age_DoubleBass),

Age_Piano #>= Age_DoubleBass + 2, 

% Clue 2 ---
% One position further to Lueg's right is Walter. 
% Walter is also one position further to the left than Sally's Dog composer.

Walter #= Lueg + 1, 
Walter #= Sally - 1, 

% Clue 3 ---
% The man on position 5 is one year younger than Pete 
% and one year older than the composer of Im Bermudadreieck.

nth1(Pete, AgeList, Age_Pete),
nth1(Bermudadreieck, AgeList, Age_Bermudadreieck),

Age_Saxophon #= Age_Pete - 1,
Age_Saxophon #= Age_Bermudadreieck + 1,

% Clue 4 ---
% One position further to the right than the 77 year old artist is 
% the composer of Wanne-Eickel-Blues.

Wanne #= AP77 + 1,

% Clue 5 ---
% One position further to right than Fritz is Franke. 
% Franke is at least 3 years older than the composer of Legende von Bergmann. 
% This composer is older than Schlüter.

nth1(Franke, AgeList, Age_Franke),
nth1(Legende, AgeList, Age_Legende),
nth1(Schlueter, AgeList, Age_Schlueter),

Franke #= Fritz + 1,
Franke #\= Legende,
Franke #\= Schlueter,
Age_Franke #>= Age_Legende + 3,
Age_Legende #> Age_Schlueter,

% Clue 6 ---
% One position further to the right than Cornelius is the 80 years old Weidemann. 
% Weidemann is also one position further to the left than Karolewicz. 
% None of them is the composer of Krösken-Tanz.

nth1(Weidemann, AgeList, Age_Weidemann),

Age_Weidemann #= 80,
Weidemann #= Cornelius + 1,
Weidemann #= Karolewicz - 1,
Weidemann #\= Kroesken,
Cornelius #\= Kroesken,
Karolewicz #\= Kroesken,

% Clue 7 ---
% Schlüter, composer of Jupps-Eck-Blues, is one position further to the right than Markus. 
% Schlüter is one position further to the left than Andi.

Schlueter #= Jupps,
Schlueter #= Markus + 1,
Schlueter #= Andi - 1,

term_variables([FirstName, LastName, Age, Song], Vars),

labeling(Vars),

write('\nPosition\t\tFirst Name\t\tLast Name\t\tAge\t\tSong\n'),
write('---------\t\t---------\t\t---------\t\t---------\t\t---------\n'),

( foreach(I, Instrument),
    foreach(IS, InstrumentS),
    param(FirstName, FirstNameS, LastName, LastNameS, AgeList, Song, SongS)
    do 
    
    printf('%w', [IS]),
    
    ( foreach(F, FirstName),
            foreach(FS, FirstNameS),
            param(I) do
            
            F == I ->
            printf('\t\t%w', [FS])
    ;
            true
    ),
    ( foreach(L, LastName),
            foreach(LS, LastNameS),
            param(I) do
            
            L == I ->
            printf('\t\t%w', [LS])
    ;
            true
    ),
    
    nth1(I, AgeList, A),
    printf('\t\t%w', [A]), 
    
    ( foreach(S, Song),
            foreach(SS, SongS),
            param(I) do
            
            S == I ->
            printf('\t\t%w\n', [SS])
    ;
            true
    )
).
```

Comment: You will see a dramatic speedup if you replace all occurrences of `nth1` with `element`. The reason is that `nth1` is nondeterministic, while `element` uses constraint propagation. The multiple calls of `nth1` lead to quite a substantial search tree.

Comment: @jschimpf Thanks for the suggestion, I will check this out